# How to configure SSL on Apache 2.4 (Windows 7)?

Tags: apache, ssl, windows-7

I'm trying to install and configure Apache 2.4 on my pc (Windows 7).

I need also PHP and SSL.

All is working fine with http and php, but I've some troubles with https.

I've search on the web for some tutorials and I've found this one: http://www.silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2009/3/31/Enabling-SSL-on-Apache-on-Windows

In my httpd-vhosts.conf file I've created two Virtual Host definitions ....

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
  DocumentRoot "D:/Cesare/Personale/DocumentRootApache"
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  ErrorLog "logs/localhost.com-error.log"
  CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common    
  <Directory "D:/Cesare/Personale/DocumentRootApache">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
  </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
   SSLCertificateFile "D:/Programmi/ApacheSoftwareFoundation/Apache24/conf/ssl/cesare.cert"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/Programmi/ApacheSoftwareFoundation/Apache24/conf/ssl/cesare.key"
   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
   DocumentRoot "D:/Cesare/Personale/DocumentRootApacheHttps"
   ServerName localhost
   DirectoryIndex index.html, index.cfm, index.php
   ErrorLog "logs/localhost.com-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
   <Directory "D:/Cesare/Personale/DocumentRootApacheHttps">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

All the directories exist on my computer, I've checked.

When I try to access with the url

```
https://localhost/index.html
```

the response is

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.
```

Any suggestions? I can give other informations about my apache configurations if needed.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact you are not able to get that file due to permissions rather than due to SSL/TLS errors suggests this is not a HTTPS set up error.

I'd suggest that you need to add this:

```
Require all granted
```

to your Directory config for your 443 vhost to allow access to this directory. You have this on your 80 vhost.